# Solving the Recurrence $ T(n) = kT(\frac{n}{k}) + k(k − 1) $

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I have the recurrence which I need to solve via telescoping and finally find the big theta time complexity:

$ T(n) = kT(\frac{n}{k}) + k(k − 1)  $

Where $ K = 9 $

I have taken $ K = 9 $, $ n=9^m$ and substituted it in the function, resulting in.

$ T(n) = 9T(\frac{9^m}{9}) + 9(9 − 1)  $

$ T(n) = 9T(\frac{9^m}{9}) + 72  $

$ T(n) = 9T(\frac{{9^m}^{-1}}{9}) + 72  $

I then proceeded to take $ T(n) $ to be $T(2^m)$

Finally I am left with:

$ F(m) = 9F(m-1) + 72  $

Provided I haven't made a major error I am not sure how to procede from here, any assitance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to solve this one with telescoping?  That isn't the most straightforward way.  You'd basically have to solve the problem to figure out what the telescoping sequence is.

Comment: Anyway, the direct way is let $S(n) = T(k^n) = k~S(n - 1) + k~(k - 1)$ then solve $S$ like a normal affine recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider that $n = k^p$ is an integer power of $k$. Thus, the recurrence relation rewrites as
$$
 \underbrace{T(k^p)}_{u_p} = k\, \underbrace{T(k^{p-1})}_{u_{p-1}} + k(k-1) \, .
$$
The sequence $(u_p)_{p\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an affine recursion. Therefore, the sequence defined by $v_p = u_{p+1} - u_p$ is a geometric sequence with common ratio $k$,
$$
v_{p+1} = k u_{p+1} + k(k-1) - \left( k u_p + k(k-1)\right) = k v_p \, ,
$$
and first term $v_0 = (k-1)\left(u_0 + k\right)$. Recognizing a telescoping series, one writes
$$
u_p = u_0 + \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} v_k = u_0 + v_0\frac{1-k^p}{1-k} \, ,
$$
i.e.
$$
u_p = k^p \left(u_0 + k \right) - k \, .
$$
Finally, $u_p=\Theta(k^{p})$, and $T(n) = \Theta(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also will find interesting this article: [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)